# Meekat for second umrah

Tags: umrah

I had come from India to Mecca for umrah
And had done it now I'm here in Mecca for last 6 days
Now I want to perform umrah again from which meeqat I should wear ihram?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already in Mekka, you have to go outside the sacred area and do ihram from there.  I think the common place mekkans is a Masjid called Tanim, located beyond the haram of the city.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go to the specific Meeqat which is most important for those coming for Umrah from India i.e. Yalamlam Meeqat as you have already performed your first Umrah. Now you have three more options which are mentioned for those who are in Makkah and wish to put on their Ihram with the intention of Umrah.

Three Meeqats for Mecca living persons:

Ayesha Mosque-Taneem Mosque
Juranah Mosque
Hudaibiyah Mosque

**Reference**: **https://www.labbaikhajjumrah.co.uk/miqats-for-hajj-and-umrah/**